# POST request 404 Not Found Error in Postman

Tags: node.js, database, mongoose, postman, backend

For the life of me I can not figure this out.  This error is telling me either

- no such URL
- I do not have access to the api / organization at all.

I am building my backend for the app.  I have successfully connected the Database and a port for the server.  I am trying to create my first route -- post and keep getting the 404 error.

My routes.js

```
const ContactList = require('./Model/ContactList');

app.post('/add-contact', async (request, response) => {
  const contactList = new ContactList(request.body);
  try {
    await contactList.save();
    response.status(201).json({
      status: 'Success',
      data: {
        contactList
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    response.status(500).json({
      status: 'Failed',
      message: err
    });
  }
});
```

My Schema Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ContactListSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  first_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  last_name: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  birthday: {
    type: Date,
    required: false
  }
});

const ContactList = mongoose.model('ContactList', ContactListSchema);
module.exports = ContactList;
```

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGg5F.png)

- I deleted the files and re did them incase it was a typing error that I am missing
- double checked the port to make sure its the right port number
- Made it https instead of http
- added / to the end incase it was being finicky
- Deleted MongoDB cluster and created a new one
- Changed the route to http://localhost:8080/api/add-contact

Comment: Post the rest of your code. What is `app` and where does it come from?

Comment: Just checking -- you remembered to launch your server first?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the information that you share, could be various error that has as result the error 404.

Some steps to check all works like as should:

1. Check the URL: First, ensure that you are using the correct URL to access your API endpoint. In your case, if you're running your server locally on port 8080, the URL should be http://localhost:8080/add-contact.
2. Check Server Port: Verify that your server is running on the correct port (8080 in this case) and that you're listening for incoming requests on that port.
3. Check Postman Configuration: Make sure you are sending the request body in the correct format (JSON) and it matches the structure expected by your route handler.

Set Headers: You need to set the "Content-Type" header to indicate that you're sending JSON data. Add a header with the key "Content-Type" and the value "application/json".

```
    {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "email": "john@example.com",
      "phone": 1234567890,
      "birthday": "1990-01-01"
    }
```

4. Use console log to debbug: Insert some console log statements in your route handler to see if the handler is being executed when you send a request. This can help you identify whether the route is registered and accessed correctly.

```js
app.post('/add-contact', async (request, response) => {
  console.log('Received a POST request to /add-contact');
  
  // ... rest of your code ...
});
```

Console log on Express Initialization

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

// ... define your routes and middleware ...

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Some website that could help to you:

[Postman docs](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/requests/)

[Tutorial from tutorialPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postman/postman_post_requests.htm)

If you still has issues, please share more information to help you.

Comment: Thanks Fransisco! I added the console.log and it is not showing up in my terminal and I don't it will if I am getting the 404 error..  I checked the URL, the server port, made sure the header content type was application/json . format is in json.  Deleted and rebuilt the backend again and no luck

Comment: Oh! I see... Did you init your server ??. You have to open another terminal and start your server and check if the console.log appears. 
Follow this tutorial: [Tutorial Api Mongo](https://dev.to/staunchcfo/build-a-rest-api-with-node-express-mongodb-post-man-49ca)